# ZF2 count rows in database

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

Hi i have this problem: i want to count rows in ZF2 in database and i use this code in controller:

```
        public function getProductTable()
 {
    if (!$this->productTable) {
         $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
         $this->productTable = $sm->get('Product\Model\ProductTable');
     }
     return $this->productTable;
 }

 public function productCounter($user_id){
            //product Count
   $productCount = $this->getProductTable()->select(); // error reported on this line
   return $productCount->from("product")->where(array('user_id' => $user_id))->count();
 }
```

function getProductTable() is working because i use it on other lines. mistake is reported on marked line in code. Where is my mistake? .. Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Change the productCounter function to this

```
public function productCounter($user_id) {
    return $this->getProductTable()->select(array('user_id' => $user_id))->count();
}
```

Select method returns the results right away, not the Select object.

Comment: Call to undefined method Product\Model\ProductTable::select() in xxx

Comment: What type of object is ProductTable?

Comment: Please check the new answer. It would work if your passing the `TableGateway` object while creating the object of `ProductTable` in the Module.php -> `Product\Model\ProductTable` factory definition.

Answer (score 0):

I hope along with `getProductTable()` and `productCounter()` functions you also have the following constructor too;

```
protected $tableGateway;
.....
...
public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}`
```

If so then try this -

`public function productCounter($user_id) {
   return $this->tableGateway->select(array('user_id' => $user_id))->count();
 }`

This should work fine.

---

Now if you don't have such a constructor then there is lot to be done if you want to use the TableGateway for executing the queries -

1. Have such a constructor first.                 //Important
2. In Product\Module.php -

   `'Product\Model\ProductTable' => function($sm) {
       $tableGateway = $sm->get('ProductTableGateway');
       $table = new ProductTable($tableGateway);
       return $table;
   },
   'ProductTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
       $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
       $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
       $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Product());
       return new TableGateway('product', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
   },`
3. Now try that `productCounter()` function.

I hope it helps.